# Exchange 07 to 07 mailbox migration using local continuous replication

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

I have an existing Exchange Server `ex0` and a fresh Exchange Server `ex1`, both 2007SP3. The servers are in different sites so users cannot access mailboxes on `ex1` as from my understanding, a standalone CAS is required for this.

I am thinking of doing the following:

1. Enable local continous replication of the storage group on `ex0` to a mapped drive that points to the corresponding storage group folder on `ex1`
2. At some point when the replication is done (small number of users and volume of mail), say on a late night on the weekend, disable CAS on `ex0` (or otherwise redirect requests on the server-side from `ex0` to `ex1`) AND change the public DNS name of the CAS so that it points to `ex1`.

Will my plan work? If not, please explain what I can do to fix it.

Comment: 1. There is no CAS in Exchange Server 2007. 2. You're misunderstanding LCR. 3. If you're planning to get rid of ex0 then why not just move the mailboxes from ex0 to ex1? 4. If you want to keep both servers as part of your DR plan then look into setting up CCR.

Comment: @joeqwerty there is CAS role in 2007, I just uninstalled and installed it... as for why I want to do it this way, I am migrating from an on-premise Exchange server to one hosted at a datacenter, and the on-premise Internet connection is quite slow. I wanted to do this without incurring much downtime...

Comment: My bad. Apologies.

Comment: What's your goal here? To move all the mailboxes to ex1?